# Handshake not capturing on wpa-psk/wpa 2 psk

Tags: wireless, wpa2-psk, airodump-ng

I'm struggling to get a handshake from my router when using airodump.

```
airmon-ng
airmon-ng check kill 
airodump-ng wlan0mon
airodump-ng -c (channel)--bssid(adress)-w (.cap file locand name) wlan0mon
aireplay-nd -0 00 -a(mac adress) -c (client) wlan0mon
```

It is being deauth for several hours but can't capture the handshake file.

Answer (score 1):

The handshake appears on a correct connection. If you set the deauth for hours probably the client is not able to connect correctly. You should perform a small deauth (for a short time) and letting the clients to reconnect.

Other possibility is that you are using an ineffective deauth attack. Not all attacks are affecting to all Access Points and to all clients. In my expericence, aireplay attacks are working very well against android clients for example, and for a windows client is better to use a mdk3 attack.